# Android Studio with Java Library Module Unable to load test resources

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have an Android Studio Project with a Java library inner module that has tests with test resources.  Yet when i run the tests I am not able to retrieve the artifacts.  This seems to work fine in a pure java gradle project (in eclipse at least).

meaning For java plugin:

```
src/main/java
src/main/test
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

Under the resources directory i have a crt file that i want to load in my junit test.  When using any command i have come across it returns null for the resource.  Yet I have confirmed the resources are in the build folder.

Some things I Tried:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cert_format_der.crt").read(); // NPE
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/cert_format_der.crt").read(); // NPE
getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream("/cert_format_der.crt").read(); // NPE
```

Thanks

Comment: I found that using the gradle command 'test' inside android studio works though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out this seems to be a bug with Intellij and how Gradle not setting the resource directory for the test sourcesets correctly.

Adding This to the build.gradle for the module Fixes it:

```
sourceSets {
   test {
      output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
   }
}
```

Comment: Anyone wishing to follow the issue, original with workaround: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887 and live issue pending resolution is here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75991

Comment: not working. the test resources are not copied to build directory and so not in classpath.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of diverging the resources to the class output directory − as suggested by *nibbuen* − it is also possible not to touch the output directory and explicitly add it as a dependency.

```
dependencies {
  runtime files(sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir)
}
```

Comment: Tried. but the build directory does not have test resources.